# Tapestry: Ways to do page refresh

Tags: tapestry, page-refresh

What are the ways to do a page refresh in Tapestry? I know how to refresh a zone using AjaxResponseRenderer but not quite sure about a page refresh.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing in Tapestry to refresh a page as it's just Javascript:

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

The 'true' forces the browser to reload content from the server (and not use it's cache).

Comment: How do I call the "window.location.reload(true)" in Tapestry?

Answer (score 2):

Usually your page has an onActivate() method. To refresh a page you need to have injected with @Inject the PageRenderLinkSource and then use it like in the example

```
@Inject
private PageRenderLinkSource pageRenderer;

Object onActivate(){}

@OnEvent(*any event*)
Object onRefresh()
{
return pageRenderer.createPageRenderLink(YourClass.class);
}
```

Comment: You can even just: return YourClass.class; As long as that class is a tapestry page it'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking, but, for example, when I use the form in Tapestry and want to add "Reset" button to form, I mark the input button as: 
`<input t:type="submit" t:id="reset" value="${message:reset}" />`

and in class, I add:

```
 public Object onSelectedFromReset() {

       return this;

    }
```

This means that I am handling the event from reset button and I am returning **this** (the same would be if you return the page name `return "page-name"`). When you return the page, it has the same effect if you would refreshed it.